# Why does xml_parse fail when a multibyte character is present?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, multibyte

Why does the following XML not parse?

```
$testxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><string>ä</string>';
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, 'ISO-8859-1');
var_dump(xml_parse($parser, $testxml, count($testxml)));
```

Same code will parse on a WAMP setup but not on LAMP. Both running identical libraries and settings with PHP5.5.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 ????? _8-bit single-byte coded graphic character sets_

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1
Complete coverage for German language including umlauts. 
I may be wrong about multibyte.
I tried UTF-8 which breaks in all tested scenarios. 8859-1 works perfectly in some scenarios, including LAMP with PHP5.3